# oracle sql - xmltype for extracing xml value not working

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xmltype

I have the following xml in my clob field:

```
<i>7894564</i>
<se>ABC</se>
```

I'm using the following query but it yields to an error:

```
select xmltype(clob_field).extract('//se/text()').getStringVal() from tablename
```

The error is:

```
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19213: error occurred in XML processing at lines 2
LPX-00245: extra data after end of document
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 272
ORA-06512: at line 1
31011. 00000 -  "XML parsing failed"
*Cause:    XML parser returned an error while trying to parse the document.
*Action:   Check if the document to be parsed is valid.
```

Can anyone help me on this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is what is stored in your CLOB is not an XML document as it is missing a root node. Since you are scanning the whole document in your extract you could just wrap it in an element to ensure you have 1 and only 1 root, at which point your XMLTYPE cast would work.

---

A little dirty but:

```
SELECT
  XMLTYPE('<ROOT>'||clob_field||'</ROOT>').EXTRACT('//se/text()').getStringVal()
FROM tablename
```

Comment: Just to mention: In this case it might be okay, but one should avoid the *deep search* with `//`. Better was `EXTRACT('/ROOT/se/text()')`

Comment: That's a good point. I would normally coach people to only use // if you really need to search the whole document. At least try and localise as close as possible before using // so you are searching a smaller space.

Answer (score 0):

### try this:

this should work

```
  with xml_table
  as
  (
  select '<i>7894564</i>' xml_data from dual
  union
  select '<se>ABC</se>' xml_data from dual  
  )
  select xmltype(xml_data).extract('//se/text()').getStringVal() from xml_table
```